# Unable to create sqlite tables in android

Tags: android, sqlite

So I'm attempting to create a set of SQLite tables in android so I can store my data, pull it out, manipulate it and shove it back in.

The error I'm running into is:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: units (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM units
         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1318)
         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1257)
         at au.edu.murdoch.ict376.universityquest.helpers.DBHelper.getAllUnits(DBHelper.java:787)
         at au.edu.murdoch.ict376.universityquest.fragments.SettingsFragment.onCreateView(SettingsFragment.java:54)
         at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2353)
         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:995)
         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1171)
         at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:816)
         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1578)
         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:483)
         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

And I've tried everything to try to fix it. I can't work out where I'm going wrong.

Here's my DBHelper onCreate code:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // Array divider
    private static final String ARRAY_DIVIDER = "vyo6vj50fdbv";

    // The database name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UniQuest.db";

    // The table "notes"
    private static final String NOTES_TABLE_NAME = "notes";
    private static final String NOTES_COLUMN_ID = "id";
    private static final String NOTES_COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String NOTES_COLUMN_DATE = "date";
    private static final String NOTES_COLUMN_TEXT = "text";

    // The table "tasks"
    private static final String TASKS_TABLE_NAME = "tasks";
    private static final String TASKS_COLUMN_ID = "id";
    private static final String TASKS_COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String TASKS_COLUMN_DATE = "date";
    private static final String TASKS_COLUMN_TEXT = "text";
    private static final String TASKS_COLUMN_COMPLETED = "completed";

    // The table "assignments"
    private static final String ASSIGNMENTS_TABLE_NAME = "assignments";
    private static final String ASSIGNMENTS_COLUMN_ID = "id";
    private static final String ASSIGNMENTS_COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String ASSIGNMENTS_COLUMN_DUEDATE = "duedate";
    private static final String ASSIGNMENTS_COLUMN_TASKS = "tasks";
    private static final String ASSIGNMENTS_COLUMN_COMPLETED = "completed";

    // The table "achievements"
    private static final String ACHIEVEMENTS_TABLE_NAME = "notes";
    private static final String ACHIEVEMENTS_COLUMN_ID = "id";
    private static final String ACHIEVEMENTS_COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String ACHIEVEMENTS_COLUMN_CRITERIA = "criteria";
    private static final String ACHIEVEMENTS_COLUMN_COMPLETED = "completed";

    // The table "classes"
    private static final String TUTES_TABLE_NAME = "classes";
    private static final String TUTES_COLUMN_ID = "id";
    private static final String TUTES_COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String TUTES_COLUMN_DAY = "day";
    private static final String TUTES_COLUMN_TIME = "time";
    private static final String TUTES_COLUMN_TYPE = "type";
    private static final String TUTES_COLUMN_LOCATION = "location";

    // The table "grades"
    private static final String GRADES_TABLE_NAME = "grades";
    private static final String GRADES_COLUMN_ID = "id";
    private static final String GRADES_COLUMN_UNIT = "unit";
    private static final String GRADES_COLUMN_GRADE = "grade";

    // The table "units"
    private static final String UNITS_TABLE_NAME = "units";
    private static final String UNITS_COLUMN_ID = "id";
    private static final String UNITS_COLUMN_UNIT = "unit";
    private static final String UNITS_COLUMN_MARKID = "markid";

    // The table "marks"
    private static final String MARKS_TABLE_NAME = "marks";
    private static final String MARKS_COLUMN_ID = "id";
    private static final String MARKS_COLUMN_TASK = "task";
    private static final String MARKS_COLUMN_TYPE = "type";
    private static final String MARKS_COLUMN_WEIGHT = "weight";
    private static final String MARKS_COLUMN_GRADE = "grade";
    private static final String MARKS_COLUMN_UNITID = "unitid";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // Creating the tables
        db.execSQL(
                "create table " + NOTES_TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                        NOTES_COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                        NOTES_COLUMN_TITLE + " text, " +
                        NOTES_COLUMN_DATE + " text, " +
                        NOTES_COLUMN_TEXT + " text);" +

                        "create table " + TASKS_TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                        TASKS_COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                        TASKS_COLUMN_TITLE + " text, " +
                        TASKS_COLUMN_DATE + " text, " +
                        TASKS_COLUMN_TEXT + " text, " +
                        TASKS_COLUMN_COMPLETED + " text);" +

                        "create table " + ASSIGNMENTS_TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                        ASSIGNMENTS_COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                        ASSIGNMENTS_COLUMN_TITLE + " text, " +
                        ASSIGNMENTS_COLUMN_DUEDATE + " text, " +
                        ASSIGNMENTS_COLUMN_TASKS + " text, " +
                        ASSIGNMENTS_COLUMN_COMPLETED + " text);" +

                        "create table " + ACHIEVEMENTS_TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                        ACHIEVEMENTS_COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                        ACHIEVEMENTS_COLUMN_TITLE + " text, " +
                        ACHIEVEMENTS_COLUMN_CRITERIA + " text, " +
                        ACHIEVEMENTS_COLUMN_COMPLETED + " text);" +

                        "create table " + TUTES_TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                        TUTES_COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                        TUTES_COLUMN_TITLE + " text, " +
                        TUTES_COLUMN_DAY + " text, " +
                        TUTES_COLUMN_TIME + " text, " +
                        TUTES_COLUMN_TYPE + " text, " +
                        TUTES_COLUMN_LOCATION + " text);" +

                        "create table " + GRADES_TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                        GRADES_COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                        GRADES_COLUMN_UNIT + " text, " +
                        GRADES_COLUMN_GRADE + " text);" +

                        "create table " + UNITS_TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                        UNITS_COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                        UNITS_COLUMN_UNIT + " text, " +
                        UNITS_COLUMN_MARKID + " text);" +

                        "create table " + MARKS_TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                        MARKS_COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                        MARKS_COLUMN_TASK + " text, " +
                        MARKS_COLUMN_TYPE + " text, " +
                        MARKS_COLUMN_WEIGHT + " text, " +
                        MARKS_COLUMN_GRADE + " text, " +
                        MARKS_COLUMN_UNITID + " text);"
        );
    }
```

And this is the method I'm attempting to call in my fragment:

```
public List<Unit> getAllUnits() {
        List<Unit> units = new LinkedList<Unit>();

        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + UNITS_TABLE_NAME;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        Unit unit = null;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                unit = new Unit();
                unit.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                unit.setUnit(cursor.getString(1));
                unit.setMarks(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));

                units.add(unit);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return units;
    }
```

I can't figure out why the tables aren't creating, I've been pouring over it for an hour.

Answer (score 1):

`execSQL()` only runs a single query, stopping at the end of input or first `;`.

Split your `;`-separated queries to multiple `execSQL()` calls. You can uninstall your application to wipe its data in order to make `onCreate()` run again.